# What is the order-type of the set of natural numbers, when written in alphabetical order?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, logic, order-theory, puzzle

We are all familiar with the standard nomenclature for the smallish
natural numbers, such as

> one, two, three, ..., one hundred, one hundred one, ..., fifteen
>    thousand two hundred forty-nine.

I have in mind the simple [American number naming
conventions](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_numbers_in_English),
together with the [names for large
numbers](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_large_numbers). (**Update** [Names of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers) seems to be more thorough. Note to Wikipedians: should probably merge those two pages somehow.)

**Preliminary question.** Is there a sensible naming system that
provides a canonical name for every natural number?

That is, I want a naming system that extends the current naming
system sensibly in such a way that every number gets a unique name. Please provide a system and explain why it is sensible.

For example, if there were some natural way to extend the Latin naming convention indefinitely, that would be great.

Let me assume that some of you will be able to provide such a
naming system.

**Main Question.** What is the order-type of the set of natural
numbers, when written in alphabetical order?

For example, the order will not be the same as the order $\omega$
of the natural number themselves, since presumably there will be
infinitely many numbers starting with "o", as in one hundred, one
million, one thousand, and so on, and these will all be
alphabetically preceding two hundred, two million, two thousand and
so on.

So the order type will probably be related naturally $L\times 26$
for some order $L$, or actually, less than $26$, since probably not
every letter will be a legitimate first letter of a number name.

It is conceivable that the order type will depend on syntactic features of the naming convention.

Here is a part of the order, for numbers up to 100: (from [hervé
graumann
1988](http://www.graumann.net/echo/graumann/aaa_pageshtml/dladnE.html))

```
1) eight

2) eighteen

3) eighty

4) eighty-eight

5) eighty-five

6) eighty-four

7) eighty-nine

8) eighty-one

9) eighty-seven

10) eighty-six

11) eighty-three

12) eighty-two

13) eleven

14) fifteen

15) fifty

16) fifty-eight

17) fifty-five

18) fifty-four

19) fifty-nine

20) fifty-one

21) fifty-seven

22) fifty-six

23) fifty-three

24) fifty-two

25) five

26) forty

27) forty-eight

28) forty-five

29) forty-four

30) forty-nine

31) forty-one

32) forty-seven

33) forty-six

34) forty-three

35) forty-two

36) four

37) fourteen

38) hundred

39) nine

40) nineteen

41) ninety

42) ninety-eight

43) ninety-five

44) ninety-four

45) ninety-nine

46) ninety-one

47) ninety-seven

48) ninety-six

49) ninety-three

50) ninety-two

51) one

52) seven

53) seventeen

54) seventy

55) seventy-eight

56) seventy-five

57) seventy-four

58) seventy-nine

59) seventy-one

60) seventy-seven

61) seventy-six

62) seventy-three

63) seventy-two

64) six

65) sixteen

66) sixty

67) sixty-eight

68) sixty-five

69) sixty-four

70) sixty-nine

71) sixty-one

72) sixty-seven

73) sixty-six

74) sixty-three

75) sixty-two

76) ten

77) thirteen

78) thirty

79) thirty-eight

80) thirty-five

81) thirty-four

82) thirty-nine

83) thirty-one

84) thirty-seven

85) thirty-six

86) thirty-three

87) thirty-two

88) three

89) twelve

90) twenty

91) twenty-eight

92) twenty-five

93) twenty-four

94) twenty-nine

95) twenty-one

96) twenty-seven

97) twenty-six

98) twenty-three

99) twenty-two

100) two

101) zero
```

Let me add that I don't necessarily expect that the order is a well-order. For example, if we have a naming convention whereby $10^k$ is represented for large $k$ simply by repeating "penpenpenpen$\cdots$pen", then we could make a descending sequence via penpenpenpen$\cdots$pen twelve, which would descend as the number of pen's increased, since we would be replacing t with p.

Comment: For this question, I was inspired by a puzzle I saw recently online, perhaps on Twitter, but I cannot seem to find it now. It was a sequence continuation puzzle, giving a short initial segment of the order (for numbers up to 100), and then asking, what comes next?

Comment: I have a method for writing the names of numbers in alphabet: For $n$ just write a string of $n+1$ times the letter "a". So $0$ is "a", and "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" is $345$. Now the order type is again $\omega$!

Comment: Yes, Asaf, perhaps that is "sensible".

Comment: This exact question was asked two weeks ago on [r/math subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/a3qvjz/what_is_the_order_type_of_the_natural_numbers/?st=jpwntgmy&sh=d176b5b9).

Comment: @Wojowu Great! I guess the puzzle is in the air.

Comment: Let me add that the puzzle is not answered on reddit, although they have pointers to some possible naming conventions and also recognized that the order may be ill-founded.

Comment: According to one of the websites, $10^{300}$ is one novemnonagintillion in the American convention. But what do you imagine $10^{10^{300}}$ might be called then?

Comment: I don't think the American convention is complete, and the point of my preliminary question is to describe a naming convention that is, one which provides answers to all such questions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system

Comment: @Holo: Yes, that was the idea.

Comment: @AsafKaragila won't it have order type a bit bigger than $ω$? a,aa,aaa,...,b,ba,baa,baaa,...,c,...,...,bb,bba,...

Comment: @Holo: If you know of a natural number $n$ which cannot be represented as a string of $n+1$ "a"s, then we can talk about adding "b" and "c" to the representation.

Comment: @AsafKaragila if it is non-standard model of PA it has some initial segment with isomorphic to the normal model, and every element outside of this won't be in the "a"s

Comment: @Holo: It will be, the string will just be indexed with a non-standard integer.

Comment: Actually, not even all native English speakers are "familiar with" the naming scheme of your first example: in British English, 15,249 is read out as "fifteen thousand two hundred **and** forty nine". Aside from that the form of your question amounts to: "please invent something nice and then tell me what its properties are". This is not a good MSE question.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, I just learned about the British manner of using "and" in numbers today on Twitter, after having posted this question; thanks for the correction. Meanwhile, it isn't necessarily about invention, since I've learned that there are several number naming systems, including systems by Knuth and Conway, and I presume we'll get answers summarizing them before long.  As for the order type, I am inclined to think it will be something closer to a dense order, rather than a well-order as many expected at first. Lastly, I'm sorry you don't enjoy the question; I find it quite interesting.

Comment: @JDH: it's interesting-ish but too open-ended. Why don't you do some work on the specific systems you've learned about and then come back with some specific questions about any problems you have? You can't just say "I think it will be something closer to a dense order" when you don't have a specific system in mind.

Comment: I had asked the preliminary question because I assumed that there were systems already established, which I didn't know about, and I assumed that people would post explaining them. And indeed, there are such systems, which I've learned about now from the reddit site and from the Twitter discussion surrounding this question. I am looking forward to reading someone posting an account of them here; but I'll post if no other posts are forthcoming. As for analyzing them and finding the order type, I don't think it is so easy to describe the orders, since I think most of them are not well-orders.

Comment: In my remark about dense orders, I did have something more specific in mind, now that I've learned of the Conway naming scheme and the Knuth naming scheme.

Comment: What's a power tower of ten $\omega$'s?

Comment: Represent numbers in the regular "short scale" English notation system, e.g. "million", "billion", "duodecillion", etc. Call a number a ${\it term}$ if it is of the form "$n$ zillion', where zillion is one of million, billion, etc. Then the ordering should separate into discretely-ordered 'blocks' of order type one zillion, consisting of all those numbers whose leading term is "$n$ zillion" for some fixed $n$ between 0--999. Thus the exact order type depends almost entirely on the set of infinite paths through the 26-branching tree of leading terms "$n$ zillion".

Comment: More names for very large numbers: https://sites.google.com/site/pointlesslargenumberstuff/home/l/pgln2

Comment: French artist Claude Closky in 1989 wrote a conceptual poem titled "The first thousand numbers classified in alphabetical order": https://www.ubu.com/concept/closky_1000.html

Answer (score 34):

Let us consider the *digit-pronunciation* naming system, by which
one simply pronounces the digits of a number in order, so that
$7216$ is pronounced "seven two one six" and so on for any number.
Thus, we obtain a naming system of the numbers, and while it does
not extend the standard nomenclature, nevertheless I find it to be
perfectly sensible, providing a definite unique name for every
natural number. This naming system is sometimes actually used for
very large numbers, such as reading off the number on a credit
card, and it is also commonly used to help disambiguate small
numbers, such as $50$ and $15$. So I find it to be a reasonable
naming system.

Let us place the natural numbers in alphabetical order with respect
to this naming system. Thus, $882746$ appears alphabetically before
$87$, which appears before $8734$. Note that any prefix of a word
appears earlier in the alphabetical order.

**Theorem.** The order type of the natural numbers, in alphabetical
order with respect to the digit-pronunciation naming system, is
exactly $$\omega\cdot(1+\mathbb{Q})+1.$$

**Proof.** That is, we have $1+\mathbb{Q}$ many copies of $\omega$, with a
final point on top.

I will analyze the naming system with respect to base ten, but a
similar analysis works regardless of the base.

Consider first the alphabetical order of the ten digits themselves:

> eight, five, four, nine, one, seven, six, three, two, zero

Notice that these digit names are prefix-free — none of them
is an initial segment of another. Thus, when comparing the names of
two numbers, we will never be in a situation where part of one
digit is combined with part of another in order to make the
alphabetical comparison. Rather, the alphabetical order is the same
as the lexical order on the strings of digits themselves,
considered in the alphabetical digit order above.

The largest number of all, in the alphabetical order, is zero,
since no other number starts with the letter "z", and so this
number will appear as the very last entry alphabetically. This
explains the final $+1$ in the theorem claim.

The smallest number in alphabetical order, in contrast, is $8$,
since it begins with "e", and the only other numbers beginning with
"e" also begin with $8$, followed possibly by additional digits,
and thus will appear after the single-digit $8$.

The next number after $8$, alphabetically, is $88$ and then $888$
and $8888$ and so on. I claim that every number (except $0$) has an
alphabetical successor, which is simply to add a digit $8$ at the
end of the decimal representation of the number. For example, the
next number after $532876$ is $5328768$, because any other digit
sequence above the first number must either extend it or deviate
from one of those digits. But $5328768$ will be below any other
higher deviation or extension, and so it is a successor. Similarly,
$53287688$ and $532876888$ are the next few numbers, simply adding
more $8$'s at the end.

Thus, every number except $0$ in the alphabetical order is followed
by a sequence of order type $\omega$, which is obtained by simply
tacking on additional $8$s. And so the order will be a number of
copies of $\omega$, plus one more point $0$ at the top.

Let me argue that those copies of $\omega$ are themselves densely
ordered. If one number $m$ precedes another $n$ alphabetically, but
$n$ is not just adding $8$'s to the end of the decimal
representation of $m$, then either there is some alphabetically
upward deviation in the digits of $m$ to form $n$, or else $n$
extends the digits of $m$, but eventually using some digits other
than $8$. It is easy to see that we can find another number in
between, which also won't be just adding $8$s.

Perhaps it is easiest to see this by example. The number $7536$ is
alphabetically prior to $752$, since "three" is alphabetically
earlier than "two". In between these numbers, we can find $75366$,
which has it own copy of $\omega$ arising from $753668$, $7536688$,
$75366888$ and so on.

Thus, the blocks of $\omega$ obtained by appending $8$'s are
themselves densely ordered: between any two of them we can find
another.

Notice that there is a very first such block of $\omega$ in the
alphabetical order the numbers, namely, the block consisting of
$8$, $88$, $888$ and so on, which appears at the very beginning of
the numbers in alphabetical order.

There is in contrast no largest block, before the final $0$,
because if we are given any number $n$, we can append some other
digits other than $8$ to the end of the decimal representation, and
thereby find another copy of $\omega$ above $n$ in the alphabetical
order.

Thus, the $\omega$ blocks arising from appending $8$'s are
themselves densely ordered, with a first such block and no last
such block. Since there are only countably many numbers, we must
have exactly $1+\mathbb{Q}$ many such blocks of size $\omega$. And
with the final point $0$ at the very top, it follows that the order
type of the natural numbers in the digit-pronunciation naming
system is precisely $$\omega\cdot(1+\mathbb{Q})+1,$$ as claimed.
$\Box$.

Several of us had discussed this problem over beers last night in
Münster, including Stefan Hoffelner and Stefan Mesken, following my talk at the [Münster Logic
Oberseminar](http://jdh.hamkins.org/an-infinitary-logic-free-proof-of-the-barwise-extension-theorem-university-of-munster-january-2019/). Stefan Hoffelner had suggested that we consider the digit-pronunciation naming system.

Let me say finally that it seems to me that the features of the
digit-pronunciation naming system will appear essentially in all
the naming systems, and so I expect this kind of analysis to be
able to extend to the other nomenclatures, with perhaps slightly
different endpoint effects.

---

**Update (January 2023).** I wrote an essay providing an elementary account of this question and its answer and related matters on my substack blog, [The Book of Numbers](https://joeldavidhamkins.substack.com/p/the-book-of-numbers).

Comment: I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3656682/765539) regarding a beautiful geometry video you shared yesterday on Twitter.