# Understanding a method of drawing infinitely many touching circles

Tags: geometry, circles, recreational-mathematics

[Joel David Hamkins](https://twitter.com/JDHamkins) shared a beautiful [animation](https://twitter.com/matthen2/status/1256824725814120448?s=20) by [Matthew Henderson](http://www.matthen.com/) on twitter which shows a method of drawing infinitely many touching circles. I can't embed the whole video here, so I have picked several frames below.

It shows that if one fixes a vertex of a rectangle of constant area $1$, and moves around one adjacent vertex by drawing circles, then the trace of the other adjacent vertex to the fixed one will be circles as well; this gives a method of drawing infinitely many touching circles. See the correspondence between two sets of circles below. One may play around with Python to reproduce the video.

A latter tweet by Matt seems to relate to the phenomenon above: "the construction with the rectangle of constant area is circle inversion in disguise". This seems to be related to the topics of [circle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) and [inversive geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry). But I know nothing but the two links to the Wikipedia articles.

**Question**: What is the underlying mathematics of the animation? In particular, what is the "magic" in the constant area requirement for the rectangles?

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you know https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket ?

Comment: @kimchilover: thanks for that. I'm aware that it is the first link of "see also" in the Circle packing article I mentioned.

Comment: Choose a coordinate system where the fixed vertex is origin. Identify euclidean plane with complex plane. Circle inversion with respect to unit circle centered at origin corresponds to the map $\displaystyle\;z \mapsto \frac{1}{\bar{z}}$ over comple numbers. Notice the four points $0, z, z + \frac{i}{\bar{z}}, \frac{i}{\bar{z}}$ form a rectangle of area $1$. The point $\frac{i}{\bar{z}}$ is the "other vertex" your see. It is basically the point obtained by a inversion with respect to circle $|z| = 1$ followed by a counterclockwise rotation of $90^\circ$ with respect to origin.